# Unable to create Hash of Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

A loop is run three times on a text file which has certain key-value pairs. Every loop returns a new hash which are printed below. I want to store these hashes into another hash. `group1`, `group2` and `group3` are the keys for the hashes:

```
"group1"
{
    "path"=>"/tmp/",
    "max_hits"=>262144,
    "min_hits"=>5240
}

"group2"
{
    "basic_size_limit"=>262144,
    "path"=> "/usr/bin/ruby",
    "max_hits"=>2412,
    "min_hits"=>871
}

"group3"
{
    "path"=>"/usr/tmp/",
    "basic_time_limits"=>[26214400, 26214401, 26214402],
}
```

I initialized the above hashes as `groups = Hash.new` and not I want to store them into a hash of hashes. I thought of initialising the bigger hash like `group_of_groups = Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new}`.

```
group_of_groups = Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new}
Loop i in 1 .. 3
    groups = Hash.new
    ####
        Do something and add to the hash groups
    ####
    key_name = "group" + i
    group_of_groups[key_name] = groups
end Loop
```

But it only gives me `{"group1"=>{}, "group2"=>{}, "group3"=>{}}`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It is unclear what values you already have. Are the 3 groups as above in individual hashes as variables?  Please edit to show more of the real Ruby code and demonstrate the source of those 3 hashes (also I see `"path"= "/usr/bin/ruby"` with an incorrect operator `=` instead of `=>`)

Comment: These are three different hashes that I printed. I corrected the error of `=` n `=>`. I put more info here

Comment: I understand that they are 3 different hashes, but are they stored in variables, as an Array, or otherwise?

Comment: A loop is run three times that generates three different hashes and one by one I put each hash into the bigger one. But when I print it after the loop, the bigger hash prints only keys but no values! Actually the original program is pretty big.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am updating the question with more info.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have added more information. Kindly see if it helps

Answer (score 3):

If you have your 3 hashes in 3 variables group1, group2, & group3, you can make a hash with the hashes like this:

```
group1 = {
    "path"=>"/tmp/",
    "max_hits"=>262144,
    "min_hits"=>5240
}

group2 = {
    "basic_size_limit"=>262144,
    "path"=> "/usr/bin/ruby",
    "max_hits"=>2412,
    "min_hits"=>871
}

group3 = {
    "path"=>"/usr/tmp/",
    "basic_time_limits"=>[26214400, 26214401, 26214402],
}

group_of_groups = {"group1"=>group1, "group2"=>group2, "group3"=>group3}

# result
{
    "group1" => {
        "path"=>"/tmp/",
        "max_hits"=>262144,
        "min_hits"=>5240
    }, 
    "group2" => {
        "basic_size_limit"=>262144,
        "path"=> "/usr/bin/ruby",
        "max_hits"=>2412,
        "min_hits"=>871
    },
    "group3" => {
        "path"=>"/usr/tmp/",
        "basic_time_limits"=>[26214400, 26214401, 26214402],
    },
}
```

Keep in mind that everything in Ruby is by reference, so modifying a hash inside of the group_of_groups will also modify the original hash.

Comment: Your answer gave me the hint to the solution. I was actually clearing the hash at the end of every loop, as a result of which it ended but being deleted from everywhere as it was being passed by reference!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize everything in one go, you could write it as:

```
group_of_groups = { 
    "group1" => {
        "path"=>"/tmp/",
        "max_hits"=>262144,
        "min_hits"=>5240
    },
    "group2" => {
        "basic_size_limit"=>262144,
        "path"=> "/usr/bin/ruby",
        "max_hits"=>2412,
        "min_hits"=>871
    },
    "group3" => {
        "path"=>"/usr/tmp/",
        "basic_time_limits"=>[26214400, 26214401, 26214402],
    }
}
```

The newlines make it clear what belongs to what, but are not required.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you can also do this if you need to build the hash programmatically:

```
group1 = {
    "path"=>"/tmp/",
    "max_hits"=>262144,
    "min_hits"=>5240
}

group2 = {
    "basic_size_limit"=>262144,
    "path"=> "/usr/bin/ruby",
    "max_hits"=>2412,
    "min_hits"=>871
}

group3 = {
    "path"=>"/usr/tmp/",
    "basic_time_limits"=>[26214400, 26214401, 26214402],
}

group_of_groups = 
    ["group1", "group2", "group3"].each_with_object({}) do |sub_hash_name, new_hash|
        new_hash[sub_hash_name] = instance_eval(sub_hash_name)
    end

# Result
{
    "group1" => {
        "path"=>"/tmp/",
        "max_hits"=>262144,
        "min_hits"=>5240
    }, 
    "group2" => {
        "basic_size_limit"=>262144,
        "path"=> "/usr/bin/ruby",
        "max_hits"=>2412,
        "min_hits"=>871
    },
    "group3" => {
        "path"=>"/usr/tmp/",
        "basic_time_limits"=>[26214400, 26214401, 26214402],
    },
}
```

Comment: It is not appropriate or advisable to use an eval in a case like this.

Comment: @Gravatite because it is fragile - if someone decides to change the names of the local variables, they might not know to change the string values of the array?

Comment: For two reasons.  First, Ruby supports proper reflection, so there's no reason to use an eval to get a variable.  The second is more of a philosophical issue in that eval often leads to a variety of evils from security vulnerabilities to difficult to diagnose bugs and all manner of other issues.  A quick google search should turn up more in-depth articles on when it's appropriate to use eval.

Comment: @Gravatite I'm not sure what you mean by `proper reflection`.  How would I programmatically access the contents of a variable by name if I needed to also use the name?  I already know it's not possible, due to the ambiguity of the problem, to access the name of a variable from its contents, so I couldn't put the variables themselves in a list if I needed access to their names.  The only way I know of to accomplish this is to use `eval` without resorting to creating a static hash.  Although, you could replace the name list above with `local_variables.select { |v| !x.start_with?('_').to_s }`